# Why is this JFrame not being sized right?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

for some reason, this JFrame is drawing 500 by 470 pixels.  It's throwing off my calculations, even on the most basic scale.  The code is so basic, I would think it would be accurate.  Am I just missing something obvious here?  It seems like setSize has always worked before, so what is diferent.  Can I not use game.WINDOW_WIDTH?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Game extends JPanel implements KeyListener, MouseListener {

    //Gamestate stats
    int level = 0; // 0 is menu, 1 is options, 2 is win, 3 is death, 4 is level 1

    final String WINDOW_TITLE = "Platformer a.v.0.1"; // window stats
    final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;
    final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;

    int mouseX; // stats for mouse, keyboard, ect
    int mouseY;

    // Level 0 buttons, parameters, ect
    int lv0ButtonOneX = WINDOW_WIDTH/4;
    int lv0ButtonOneY = WINDOW_WIDTH/2;
    int lv0ButtonOneS = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();

        JFrame window = new JFrame(game.WINDOW_TITLE);
        window.setSize(game.WINDOW_WIDTH,game.WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        window.add(game);
        game.addKeyListener(game);
        game.addMouseListener(game);
        game.requestFocusInWindow();

        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        while(true) {
            game.repaint();
            game.customUpdate();
        }
    }

    public void customUpdate() {
        if(level == 0) {
            if(mouseX > lv0ButtonOneX &&
                    mouseX < lv0ButtonOneX + lv0ButtonOneS &&
                    mouseY < lv0ButtonOneY + lv0ButtonOneS &&
                    mouseY > lv0ButtonOneY) {
                level = 4;
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if(level == 0) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0,0,WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT); // draw window          needs to be first in order to be drawn over

            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.fillRect(lv0ButtonOneX,lv0ButtonOneY,lv0ButtonOneS,lv0ButtonOneS); // draw buttons

            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawString("Start",lv0ButtonOneX + lv0ButtonOneS/4,lv0ButtonOneY + lv0ButtonOneS/2);
        }
        if(level == 4) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(0,0,WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT); // draw window          needs to be first in order to be drawn over

            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.fillRect(0,WINDOW_HEIGHT-20,WINDOW_WIDTH,20); // creates floor at bottom - 20 for standing.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX = e.getX();
        mouseY = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to account for the 'Title Bar' at the top of the window.  It is about 30 high.

Comment: How did you came to this conclusion? How did you get 470 pixels instead of 500? What is "always worked before"?

Comment: You're setting the size of the JFrame the same as your drawing JPanel.  The only Swing component that you should set the size for is the drawing JPanel.  Let the JFrame pack method figure out the sizes of the rest of the components, including the JFrame itself.

Comment: It was the Title bar.  I got the information by printing the mouse x and mouse y.  Can you give me a small example of how I would change the size of the JPanel?  I don't get how that works.

Comment: Windows have borders, which take up space.  Instead of calling `setSize`, you should be calling `pack` and allow the API to pack the frame around the content, this would require to establish the requirements of the size within the components themselves. This is can be achieved by overriding the `getPreferredSize` of the `Game` class, in this case.

Comment: Don't override `paint`, override `paintComponent`. Also call the paint method's `super` method to make sure you are honouring the contract of the paint methods

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

```
    window.setSize(game.WINDOW_WIDTH,game.WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    window.add(game);
    game.addKeyListener(game);
    game.addMouseListener(game);
    game.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Solution:

```
    window.setSize(game.WINDOW_WIDTH,game.WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.add(game);
    game.addKeyListener(game);
    game.addMouseListener(game);
    game.requestFocusInWindow();

    window.setVisible(true);
```

Do not make the JFrame visible before adding Objects to it.

Comment: Why is making it visible after adding objects to it impprtant?